# Repaint eyes of a stuffed animal

Tags: paint

I have an old stuffed animal, that's eyes are quite rubbed off. [image: animal]What kind of paint is suited to repaint them and won't wear off fast? I guess acrylic paint or a black marker are not ideal... do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Edit: it is my animal I have since my childhood. Ofc I don't lick it and there is no child in the house, but it gets cuddled at night, so it is in contact with human skin. Additionally, it is washed very rarely (once every few years) by hand.

Comment: Two questions that might help to clarify what you need: a) does this stuffed animal belong to a small child that might lick at the eyes and b) do you put it in the wash occasionally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best thing is the acrylic paint uses for plastic models followed by a couple of coats of gloss acrylic varnish. This will be pretty durable and should give a good result. They paint system sold by Games Workshop is pretty good quality.

You will want to thoroughly clean the surface before applying the paint alcohol is probably the best thing for this. It will also help of you scuff up the surface with wire wool although this does mean that you will probably need to paint the white parts as well.

You may also want to mask of the fur around the eyes (assuming they aren't removable) you could do this with a piece of thin plastic cut from a drink bottle, food packaging or similar, Cut a large disk and cut a slit in it so you can slip it behind the eye.

Comment: It might not be obvious, but the eyes are plastic and already have some deep scratches. Would you recommend to scuff them anyway?

Comment: yeah if they already have scratches do don;t have anything to lose b y giving them a rub down. For the paint all you need it to do if just create a more matt surface but that could be an opportunity to reduce the scratches as well.

Answer (score 4):

No, get glass paint, more specifically black glass paint.

Acrylic is just like a plastic sticker and won't hold up in a washing machine for more than a couple washes, even when varnished; the basic adherence is less than a glass paint.

Put him in a pillow case with lots of fabric conditioner. Tie it up tight, blow-dry him for 5 to 10 minutes when he comes out, paint the glass paint, brush him. Blow dry and comb him after 24 hours, that's the best you'll get besides handing him into a teddy bear hospital.